# Not updating discriminator when property type changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've got an entity that has a property that's an abstract type. This creates a one-to-one relationship that uses table-per-hierarchy inheritance. Everything seems like it's working correctly.

I can create an Item and set the `Base` property to `ConcreteOne`; everything saves correctly. However, when I try to update `Base` to `ConcreteTwo`, EF updates the `Base` record in the database with the new user value, it doesn't update the discriminator for the type. So the extra data for `ConcreteTwo` gets persisted, but the discriminator still says `ConcreteOne`.

The following is a simple example that exposes the problem

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            App_Start.EntityFrameworkProfilerBootstrapper.PreStart();

            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>());

            // Create our item with ConcreteOne for Base
            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                var item = new Item
                    {
                        Base = new ConcreteOne { Name = "Item", Data = 3 }
                    };
                context.Items.Add(item);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Update Base with a new ConcreteTwo
            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                var item = context.Items.FirstOrDefault();

                var newBase = new ConcreteTwo()
                    {
                        Item = item,  
                        Name = "Item 3", 
                        User = new User { Name = "Foo" }
                    };

                // If I don't set this to null, EF tries to create a new record in the DB which causes a PK exception
                item.Base.Item = null;  
                item.Base = newBase;

                // EF doesn't save the discriminator, but DOES save the User reference
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Retrieve the item -- EF thinks Base is still ConcreteOne
            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                var item = context.Items.FirstOrDefault();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Name, item.Base.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Base Base { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Base
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConcreteOne : Base
    {
        public int Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConcreteTwo : Base
    {
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When the changes are saved, EF generates the following SQL:

```
update [dbo].[Bases]
set    [Name] = 'Item 3' /* @0 */,
       [User_Id] = 1 /* @1 */
where  (([Id] = 1 /* @2 */)
        and [User_Id] is null)
```

So it's almost correct, but I'd expect to see `[Discriminator] = 'ConcreteTwo'` in the update statement. Are my expectations unfounded or am I doing something wrong?

As a test, I tried using table-per-type and the the entry was removed from the `ConcreteOne` table and added to the `ConcreteTwo` table as I would expect. So it works, but my real application has at least seven sub-types and the SQL statement to retrieve the `Base` property got really nasty. So I'd certainly like to accomplish this using TPH, if possible.

**Update:**
I've verified that the problem exists in EF5 as well as EF6.

Comment: If EF supports updating from 1 type to another. That's baddddddd! Nasty nasty EF. Looks like its working as intended by NOT updating it.

Comment: Why wouldn't it support changing types?  As a trivial example, if a person had a property PrimaryTransportation of type Vehicle, wouldn't it make sense to allow them to change that from a car to a boat?

Comment: A Car cannot change to a Boat. If a persons primary mode of transport changed, he doesn't magically turn his Car into a Boat. He buys a second mode of transport.

Comment: If you're using `PrimaryTransportation` as a type then that's bad design.

Comment: I agree that the person's car does not turn into a boat, but their primary transportation could.  I'd use `PrimaryTransportation` as a property, and it would be of type `Vehicle`.  I don't care if EF wants to delete the ConcreteOne record and create a ConcreteTwo record; that's fine.  My point is that it's doing neither using TPH but does the latter using TPT.

Comment: Think in terms of objects; you're setting your Base property to a **new instance** of an object.  It is not possible to cast ConcreteOne to ConcreteTwo by definition in your inheritance hierarchy.  First thoughts, I expect to be able to do this, but a new instance would translate to a new record in the database, not an update to an existing one.

Comment: @Phill I disagree that it's bad design, think of the Customer -> Order example.  An Order object has a Customer.  That Customer could be a Company or an Individual (potentially).  Would you create two mutually exclusive properties Order.Company and Order.Individual?

Comment: @chappo You're right that what I'm asking should translate into a delete of the original record and an insert of the new one. And that's what EF does when I use table-per-type hierarchy. And I'd be 100% fine with it if EF wanted to do the same thing with table-per-hierarchy as well.

Comment: @Phill was reading this question as a many-to-one, my bad... please ignore the comments

Comment: To answer this question it might help to understand the requirement being solved for, if only to prove that the expectation is moot.  To quote the `PrimaryTransportation` example, this would normally be represented via a relationship between a Person and a Vehicle, not a direct navigation to a Vehicle.  It's hard to see where an implementation like this would actually be applied.

Answer (score 0):

This question is based on the expectation of an update taking place, which is seemingly a debatable expectation.  Currently your best bet if the TPH hierarchy is not functioning as expected, and considering EF6 is currently in beta, is to start a discussion on the [Codeplex forums](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/create).

Comment: I will look at the forums to see if anyone else has had this issue, but I've verified that the problem occurs in EF5 as well. Also, I'm really just looking for my new object to get persisted and the old one to be deleted. I started down the update path because EF is generating an UPDATE statement when it saves my changes in the Base table.

Comment: Something else occurred to me.  Does the following code work? (I can't run this myself right now)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your model:

```
public enum BaseType
{
    ConcreteOne = 1,
    ConcreteTwo = 2
}

public abstract class Base
{
   ...
   public BaseType BaseType { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

And in the OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Base>()
                .ToTable("Base");

    modelBuilder.Entity<ConcreteOne>()
                .Map(t => t.Requires(m => m.BaseType).Equals(BaseType.ConcreteOne))
                .ToTable("ConcreteOne");

    modelBuilder.Entity<ConcreteTwo>()
                .Map(t => t.Requires(m => m.BaseType).Equals(BaseType.ConcreteTwo))
                .ToTable("ConcreteTwo");
}
```

Comment: This would cause EF to use table-per-type, which I'd like to avoid.  I've already verified that TPT **does** work as expected, but I'm trying to accomplish this using TPH.

Answer (score -1):

I would expect this to create a new instance (record) with a ConcreteTwo discriminator.

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
    var item = context.Items.FirstOrDefault();
    var newBase = new ConcreteTwo()
    {
        Name = "Item 3", 
        User = new User { Name = "Foo" }
    };

    item.Base = newBase;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I would expect that to work as well; however, it doesn't. This code will cause a PK exception because it's trying to insert a new ConcreteTwo record without deleting the original ConcreteOne record first. With one-to-one relationships, the PK of the dependent record should equal the main record. If I add in the `item.Base.Item = null` line before setting `item.Base = newBase`, EF marks the original as deleted and the new one as added. But then it translates that into an UPDATE statement...

Comment: Apologies, I overlooked the one-to-one, even though it was stated... my bad; I was reading Base as the parent in a many-to-one.  I'd say this was expected behaviour then.  If you're changing property Base to a new instance of Concrete2, what instance of Item would the original Concrete1 instance point to?  I'd say this was a model issue, not an EF issue.

Comment: I expect the original instance of ConcreteOne to go away; therefore, the isntance of ConcreteOne would no longer reference **any** Item.  To be clear, my intention is to throw the instance of ConcreteOne away and completely replace it with an instance of ConcreteTwo.